# How can iOS Simulator windows be minimized in Xcode 9.1?

Tags: ios, swift3

How can I minimize the simulator in Xcode 9.1? I can't find any options or icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@the4kMan answer is good

Below is another way!

> Click on Simulator -> On menu bar choose Window -> Uncheck "Show Device Bezels" -> Now at top left side you will be see **(X, -, +)** button

Comment: thank you Mr.iPatel, its perfect

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **Window/Minimize** or simply press <kbd>⌘M</kbd>.

Use **Window/Minimize All** to minimize all open Simulator windows.

[image]

Comment: thank you   the4kman , it has worked